# Riccati equations for dealing with stiffness of ODEs

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, differential-equations

Early texts [Forman Acton, Numerical Methods that Work; Numerical Recipes, first edition] suggested that for integrating a stiff linear ODE it was very helpful to integrate the associated Riccati equation instead. This point was made specifically for using shooting methods, i.e. algorithms that use an initial value method to solve a boundary value problem. I have not seen any followup on this point in the literature -- the statement does not appear in later editions of Numerical Recipes, for instance -- and I'm wondering whether this Riccati methodology is no longer considered a useful way to deal with stiffness.